# Did "When Harry Met Sally" popularise the cliché of a romcom ending with one of the leads listing the other's foibles to show their love?

Tags: trope, origin

As the title suggests, I was recently watching a romcom which ended in the now clichéd fashion of the two estranged leads reconciling when one of them lists a series of the other's idiosyncrasies to show how much they cared about the other lead. The movie I primarily associate with this is *When Harry Met Sally*, which ends in the iconic New Year's Eve scene. But did *When Harry Met Sally* popularise this, or was it already an established cliché at the time? If the latter, is there an earlier film which popularised it?